# react-router-sitemap generating a sitemap.xml with just the URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to use react-router-sitemap in order to generate a sitemap.xml for our site. However, the output file is only listing the URL and not any of the routes.

Output file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url> <loc>http://localhost:3000/</loc> </url>
</urlset>
```

My Script:

```
require('babel-register');
const router = "./components/main/contentArea.tsx"

const sitemap =  require('react-router-sitemap').default;

(
    new sitemap(router)
        .build('http://localhost:3000/')
        .save('public/sitemap.xml')
);
```

Our router looks like this (we are using react-router-dom but have also tested with react-router and the output is the same still)

```
 <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/admin/users/users" component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

I've been trying for a while now and I'm quite confused as to why this approach is not working. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found 2 articles about it:

1. https://blog.josedromero.com/create-sitemap-for-your-react-app/
2. https://www.amitsn.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-sitemap-for-your-react-website-with-dynamic-content

The first one actually describes a similar issue. Perhaps creating a new clean router.ts file could help, you could try removing "component".

Also, in our implementation we import the sitemap routes like this:

```
const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;
const router = require('./sitemap-routes').default;
```

And the sitemap-routes.js looks like this:

```
import  React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
export default ( 
<Switch>
    <Route path="/en/about-us" />
    <Route path="/en/contact-us" />
</Switch>);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to import with require:
`const router = require('./components/main/contentArea.tsx').default`

I had the similar problem and it helped to call the router as router(), like this:
`

```
(
    new sitemap(router())
        .build('http://localhost:3000/')
        .save('public/sitemap.xml')
);
```

`